# How to create a common directory in a puppet defined resource

Tags: puppet

I am implementing a defined resource in puppet to create a number of websites.

One of the steps is creating the documentroot directory for the website.

My problem is that some websites can share a common documentroot. When that happens I get the error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Cannot alias File[documentroot-redirpt] to ["/var/www/vhosts/parkingyredir"] at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/xxx_corp_webserver/manifests/website.pp:164; resource ["File", "/var/www/vhosts/parkingyredir"] already declared at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/xxx_corp_webserver/manifests/website.pp:164 at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/xxx_corp_webserver/manifests/website.pp:164:3 at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/xxx_corp_webserver/manifests/init.pp:10 on node llim605
```

So, how can I create create a resource such as that it will create the directory but not complain if I try to create it serveral times?

The owner and permissions for the documentroot directory are constant.

Comment: Sorry, figured out the answer a few minutes after posting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, figured out the answer a few minutes after posting the question.

If there is potential for the resource to be redefined, just check if it has already been defined.

```
  if !defined(File[$documentroot]) {
    file { "documentroot-${title}":
      ensure => 'directory',
      path   => $documentroot,
      group  => '0',
      mode   => '0755',
      owner  => '0',
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Puppet [documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/function.html#defined) states:

> Warning: Avoid relying on the result of the `defined` function in
> modules, as you might not be able to guarantee the evaluation order
> well enough to produce consistent results. This can cause other code
> that relies on the function’s result to behave inconsistently or fail.

An alternative (and perhaps more reliable) solution would be to use the `ensure_resource` function from [puppetlabs-stdlib](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib/blob/master/REFERENCE.md#ensure_resource). It creates the resource only if it doesn't already exist and only raises a duplicate declaration error if the resource already exists and doesn't have matching parameters.

```
ensure_resource('file', $documentroot, {
  ensure => 'directory',
  owner  => '0',
  group  => '0',
  mode   => '0755',
})
```